# How to select a character in a string using XPath or XQuery?

Tags: string, select, xpath, xquery

I have the following XML file:

```
<unit id="u-1.01"/>
<unit id="u-2.01"/>
```

I want to select the third character of the *id* attribute: in this case the characters are **1** and **2**.

What would be the simplest way to select the character and assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in XQuery 1.0

```
let $char := substring(@id, 3, 1) return ...
```

in XPath 2.0

```
for $char in substring(@id, 3, 1) return ...
```

Both assume that the `<unit>` element is the context item

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick follow-up question: the query returns a sequence `1 2`. How do I then return the number of distinct values in this sequence? I have trouble applying the distinct-values function.

Comment: If $v is the sequence `('1','2')` then you want `count(distinct-values($v))`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do so:

```
foreach (XmlNode item in n.ChildNodes)
        {
            string valToFind = item.Attributes["id"].Value;
            int pos=val.IndexOf(".");
            string finalVal = val.Substring(2, pos-2);//either this 
            string finalVal = val.Split('-')[1].Split('.')[0];//or this(both will work for you)


        }
```